# javascript and function to extract array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Currently I have an array "teenused" that contains a'la: "01","01","03","04","05","06","07"
I call function grindTeen in my code.

http://jsfiddle.net/sbJ9w/

Code and functions are here:

```
function grindTeen(teenused) {
  for (var i = 0; i < teenused.length; i++) {
            var arrayItem = teenused[i];
            return('<img src="/bena/design/icons/B-icons-'+arrayItem+'.png" width="33" height="33">');
            }
};
```

The function should return a string with html image `src` in it.
Appearently I'm noob in JavaScript Any suggestions how to do it better?

---

### Solution:

In my case I was so noob that I did not underestand that from XML I got back String not Array - so here's the correct solution with converting string to array: http://jsfiddle.net/SQQbe/13/

Comment: The for loop will only loop one cycle, as you instantly return string. You might want to add your strings to a buffer or instantly write it out to your page.

Comment: OT: Function name `grindTeen`, parameter name `teenused` – wtf are you programming there …? :-)

Comment: What is the problem with your current code? You want to make it "better" in terms of ... ?

Comment: Your function do return an image with src, but maybe you want to return several img objects for the whole array?

Comment: To everyone wondering mu usage of words - those are not in English nor anyhow related to english :D

@apelsinapa - yes I would like every number to be different image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, your loop only iterates once because you have `return` statement in there, that returns the value from the function. What you need to do is store the results and then return them in the end.

```
function grindTeen(teenused) {
  var images = [];
  var arrayItem = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < teenused.length; i++) {
       arrayItem = teenused[i];
       images.push('<img src="/bena/design/icons/B-icons-'+arrayItem+'.png" width="33" height="33">');
  }
  return images;
};

var teenImages = grindTeen(teenused);

// take the items in the teenImages list and make it into a string separated by space
var teenImagesHtml = teenImages.join(' ');
```

You can read more about `.join()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Here's the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/amyamy86/V4Rwh/

**Updated:**

For array `['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06']` the output will be (if put into the `<div>`):

```
<div id="c">
    <img src="/bena/design/icons/B-icons-01.png" width="33" height="33">
    <img src="/bena/design/icons/B-icons-02.png" width="33" height="33">
    <img src="/bena/design/icons/B-icons-03.png" width="33" height="33">
    <img src="/bena/design/icons/B-icons-04.png" width="33" height="33">
    <img src="/bena/design/icons/B-icons-05.png" width="33" height="33">
    <img src="/bena/design/icons/B-icons-06.png" width="33" height="33">
</div>
```

Comment: Does not work tho... outputs:  "01","01","03","04","05","06","07" :S

Comment: @PikkKristjan Did you not want the output of the tags to be `<img src="/bena/design/icons/B-icons-01.png" width="33" height="33">`, `<img src="/bena/design/icons/B-icons-02.png" width="33" height="33">`, etc... ??

Comment: Yes - but appearently I'm still doing sth wrong - I do not get same output :S

Comment: Yes - but appearently I'm still doing sth wrong - I do not get same output :S

But I cannot put them in div - they are part of google maps marker html content... With every marker has its own 1-7 images... So it must be output to string that I could add to html content... Also - is there anything different with IE and FF because I couldnt get your fiddle to work with FF but with IE it works as you said...

Comment: @PikkKristjan It's not showing up because IE and FF handle *broken images` different, FF shows nothing, while IE displays the *broken image icon*. Either I updated fiddle with some CSS to show that the `<img>` tags are still there. As for having it in a string, in my example the `teensImagesHtml` contains the HTML content as string:"  `<img src="/bena/design/icons/B-icons-01.png" width="33" height="33">
    <img src="/bena/design/icons/B-icons-02.png" width="33" height="33">  <img src="/bena/design/icons/B-icons-03.png" width="33" height="33"> <img ...` "

Comment: Hi, my current code:
Everything in function grindTeen is same as in yours jsfiddle.
other code is:
var teenused = [markers[i].getAttribute("teenused")];
var teenImages = grindTeen(teenused);
var teenImagesHtml = teenImages.join(' ');
teenused outputs: "04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12","13","14","15","16"
teenimageshtml outputs: 
<img src="/bena/design/icons/B-icons-&quot;04&quot;,&quot;05&quot;,&quot;06&quot;,&quot;07&quot;,&quot;08&quot;,&quot;09&quot;,&quot;10&quot;,&quot;11&quot;,&quot;12&quot;,&quot;13&quot;,&quot;14&quot;,&quot;15&quot;,&quot;16&quot;.png"height="33"width="33">

Comment: I think that main problem in my case is that I can't get result from xml to work as array and it goes as string... Have tried different scenarios - still no go - othervise your solution is the best :D